# Old Gregory had a farm: The Missing Eggs

Tags: pattern, number-sequence, mystery

Gregory is a farmer and every morning he makes sure to harvest the eggs of his chickens. He has 72 chickens and 12 chickens in each cage, so a total of 6 cages. Each of his chickens lays only one egg per day.

One morning, Gregory suddenly found out that in cage 1, the 4th and 7th chicken did not lay any egg for the day. He then thought that maybe the chickens are stressed. Then the next day, the same happened to 2 chickens in cage 2. The 9th and 12th chickens had no eggs. The next day, only the 6th chicken in cage 3 and the next day the 2nd and 8th chickens in cage 4.

He then saw a pattern that every day a new cage was having a problem. So, he planned to guard cage 5 the whole night. While guarding that night, he heard movement and rushed to the cage and saw a shadow. He quietly watched the person and saw that they were stealing his eggs. The thief ran away after stealing an egg. Gregory checked and found out that the lost egg was from the 5th chicken.

Gregory had enough and planned to set a trap. Can you help Gregory capture the thief? If you will help Gregory, on which chicken(s) will you put the trap?

**HINT 1**

> Gregory has a brother named Christian

**HINT 2**

> Cage 5 was ransacked on a Friday night

ADDED HINTS:

**HINT 3**

> Born in 16th century, Gregory is very superstitious

**HINT 4**

> After investigating, Gregory found out that the thief was Jason from the other town

Comment: I suspect they were *Easter* eggs...

Comment: haha but I thought it should be held on a Sunday?

Comment: Is it relevant how the numbers are distributed in each cage?
As in: is it relevant if they are 4x3, 3x4, 2x6, 6x2, .. and in what order they are numbered?

(I was thinking Braille, but that's 6 dots per character)

Comment: Cage size is irrelevant. Order is relevant. Chickens are distributed equally :)

Comment: Does Gregory like to leap around a lot?

Comment: That's an egg-cellent puzzle !

Comment: @Mekalikot Can there be 3 eggs stolen? Because for cage 4 i get 2nd, 3rd and 11th as solution. Is it random that 11 - 3 = 8 fits exactly the given information for cage 4? If it is not i think i'd have the right answer.

Comment: Just lock the door and you're good to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short answer

It's about

> days of the week on different months of the year.

The answer is

> the 1st and 10th chickens will be targeted in the 6th cage.

### Fuller explanation

There are 12 chickens in each cage, corresponding to the 12 months of the year. "Gregory" is a hint to use the Gregorian calendar; "Jason" is a hint to the months (JFMAMJ**JASON**D); and "Friday night" is a hint to the days of the week.

- On the first day, the 4th and 7th chickens' eggs are stolen; in 2013 (say), April and July began on Mondays.
- On the second day, the 9th and 12th chickens' eggs are stolen; in 2014 (the next year), September and December began on Mondays.
- On the third day, the 6th chicken's egg is stolen; in 2015, June began on a Monday.
- On the fourth day, the 2nd and 8th chickens' eggs are stolen; in 2016, February and August will begin on Mondays.
- On the fifth day, the 5th chicken's egg is stolen; in 2017, May will begin on a Monday.
- Finally, January and October are the only months in 2018 which will begin on a Monday, so it's the 1st and 10th chickens the thief will target in cage 6.

Thanks to **f''** and others for help with the solution. And nice puzzle :-)

### OP's intended explanation

It's all about Friday the 13th. Cages 1-6 represent the years 2001-2006 while the 12 chickens represent the months. There were Friday the 13ths in April and July 2001, September and December 2002, June 2003, February and August 2004 (leap year, like 2016), May 2005, and January and October 2006.

Comment: April and July in 2014 began on Tuesdays!

Comment: I think you're very close to the answer but indeed Monday doesn't work and also thursday and friday not

Comment: Why is Tuesday skipped?

Comment: It just doesn't quite feel right yet... Next year's January starts on Friday. Following your logic the first chicken's egg should've been stolen on the first day as well.

Comment: @Christoph In any leap year, Jan, Apr, and Jul will start on the same day. In any non-leap year, Feb and Aug won't start on the same day. I think the OP may have slipped up...

Comment: My guess is you should take the year 1582 :) that's in the 16th century and is the year the Gregorian Calendar was introduced. You'll see then that indeed Sunday is skipped. I think everything fits. The answer will then be that on the 6th day chicken 1 and 10 will be stolen

Comment: It all works if you start at 2017 and count which months start on Saturdays. I don't know if it's supposed to be 2017 in particular or some other year with the same pattern.

Comment: @randal'thor I mean 2017 for the first day, 2018 for the second day, and so on. The fourth day ends up on 2020 (a leap year) and so Feb. and Aug. both start on Saturday that year.

Comment: @IvoBeckers Good thought, but Sep 1582 began on a Saturday and Dec 1582 on a Wednesday :-(

Comment: weird, the Calendar application in OS X says that Sep and Dec are on the same day. but indeed it's not right then either. 4th day is wrong then. http://i.stack.imgur.com/qzW0z.png

Comment: @IvoBeckers The Julian December starts on the same day as the Julian September. The Gregorian December starts on a different day. See http://5ko.free.fr/en/jul.php?y=1582 for a comparison between the two calendars.

Comment: @IvoBeckers In that image, you also have all days appearing in October, rather than 5th-14th missing!

Comment: @f'' Thanks - you're right. I've edited and credited you.

Comment: Almost guys, answer is correct 1st and 10th.

Comment: To add the explanation to the answer: it's all about friday the 13th. Cages 1-6 are years 2001-2006. 12 chickens are months. Jason is also the Jason character is friday the 13th. Great job guys, it's my first original puzzle lol

Comment: @Mekalikot OK, nice! Should I add that to my answer to get the checkmark, or is my explanation OK as well?

Comment: You can add it then i'll accept :) good job!

Comment: @Mekalikot Done! Nice puzzle :-)

Comment: @randal'thor thanks, will create more :)